unhashable type: 'mutabledensematrix' error when substituting
I am getting a TypeError: unhashable type: 'MutableDenseMatrix' errormessage when trying to substitute values into a sympy matrix, and i am perplexed as to why
x1,x2 = symbols('x1,x2', real = true)
a,b,c,d,e,f = symbols('a,b,c,d,e,f', real = true)

x = Matrix([x1,x2])
xT = x.T

A = Matrix([[a,b],[c,d]])
b = Matrix([e,f])
qx = xT * A*x + xT*b

A = A.subs({a:2,b:-1,c:-1,d:2})

I tried substituting the values in one by one, but the b and d value never changed. Of course i expected it to substitute the values into the right places, but they never did

you define b as a symbol, and use it as an element of A.  Then you redefine it as a Matrix..  In the subs you make a dict with 'Matrix:-1'.  That's what the error is about.  But which b do you have in mind?  The Matrix or the symbol in A`?

The .subs function has a different syntax: it is a list of tuples.
Code:
from sympy import *
x1,x2 = symbols('x1,x2', real = true)
a,b,c,d,e,f = symbols('a,b,c,d,e,f', real = true)

x = Matrix([x1,x2])
xT = x.T

A = Matrix([[a,b],[c,d]])
b = Matrix([e,f])
qx = xT * A*x + xT*b

print(A)
# prints Matrix([[a, b], [c, d]])

A = A.subs([(a,2),(b,1),(c,-1),(d,2)])
print(A)
# prints Matrix([[2, b], [-1, 2]])

Note that b cannot be substituted this way because it is a matrix itself.

Thank you!, i was so lost in the sauce i forgot i made b a variable in itself
